# Can a "public:" function built into a class alter the class object it was called from?

Tags: c++

apologies in advance, I feel like i'm missing something major here. Any time i call a function this way it fails to alter the objects member variable.
The easiest way for me to explain is to give an example:

```
class herp
{
private:
string derp;

public:
void mderp(herp x, string y) {x.derp = y;}
}

herp object_0;
string temp = "asdf";
object_0.mderp(object0, temp);
```

Comment: `herp`/`derp` - the new `foo`/`bar`.

Comment: Why are you using a member function if you're not referencing any of the instance variables?  Why `x.derp` instead of `herp::derp`?

Answer (score 2):

You are passing `herp x` as a value type.  In this case `x` is a copy of whatever you pass in.  If you want to directly access `x.derp`, you should pass `x` in as a reference:

```
void mderp(herp& x, string y) {x.derp = y;}
```

This should allow `x.derp` to be modified.

Answer (score 1):

The argument `herp` to is passed by value, that means it is a copy of the original `object_0`.  The `mderp` function modifies the copy, but that copy is thrown away immediately.  Try a reference.  I might do:

```
class herp  
{
    private:
    string derp;

    public:
    static void mderp(herp &x, string y) {x.derp = y;}
}

herp object_0;
string temp = "asdf";
object_0.mderp(object0, temp);
```

Here the important thing is the change `herp x -> herp& x` which means the argument is "a reference to herp" rather than an actual herp value.

In this case I also made the method static, because it can be but that is not essential.

Answer (score 1):

replace

```
x.derp = y;
```

with

```
this->derp = y;
```

Comment: Or just `derp = y` if you want to modify `this`.  But I assume the OP wants to take a `herp` argument for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

What I get from your question, is that you want to initialize the private variable of your class. But there are a couple of things wrong here. You should read more about classes.

One way:

```
class herp
{
   private:
     string derp;

   public:
      void mderp(string y) {derp = y;}
 };


    herp object_0;
    string temp = "asdf";
    object_0.mderp(temp);
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two things you should probably know.

First of all your object's member variable does not get changed because the way you wrote your code, your function `mdepr` creates a copy of the object `herp`. It then changes its member variable and destroys the object upon leaving the function. So if you want to keep your function the way it is you should use a reference or a pointer. Example:

```
void mderp(herp& x, string y) {x.derp = y;}
void mderp(herp* x, string y) {x->derp = y;}
```

The second thing is, based on your example usage of the function, you probably don't want a function like that. Member functions are meant to be used on a object and are allowed to modify it (unless they are const functions). So you can just write the following:

```
class herp
{
private:
string derp;

public:
void mderp(string y) {derp = y;}
}

herp object_0;
string temp = "asdf";
object_0.mderp(temp);
```

Hope this helps :)